# error "Can’t get button returned of \"C\"." number -1728 from button returned of "C"

Tags: applescript

```
set buttonChoice to (display dialog "Play game?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} with title "Play?")
if button returned of buttonChoice = "No" then
return "No"
end if
repeat
 set levelnum to text returned of (display dialog "How many levels will you play?" buttons {"Ok"} default answer "1" with title "Levels?")
set Letters_ to {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}
set buttonChoice2 to (choose from list Letters_ with prompt "Choose A Letter" with title "Pick One" without multiple selections allowed) as text
if button returned of buttonChoice2 = "C" then
    display dialog "You Win!" buttons {"Yay!, Proceed to next level"}
    exit repeat
else
    display dialog "Try again :("
end if
end repeat
```

Can i fix     error "Can’t get button returned of \"C\"." number -1728 from button 
              returned of "C"

Comment: This is Applescript

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you attempt to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than throwing your entire code at us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buttonChoice2` already *contains* the selected letter, so

```
set buttonChoice2 to (choose from list Letters_ with prompt "Choose A Letter" with title "Pick One" without multiple selections allowed) as text
if buttonChoice2 = "C" then
    display dialog "You Win!" buttons {"Yay!, Proceed to next level"}
    exit repeat
else
    display dialog "Try again :("
end if
```